# Unable to render (double) nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have 3 models, Classses, ClassPrices & Bookings. ClassPrices belongs to Classses & Bookings belong to ClassPrices. I'm having trouble rendering the form for Bookings on the ClassPrices' page.

**1. routes.rb**

```
resources :classses do
  resources :class_prices do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

**2. class_price.rb**

```
class ClassPrice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :classs
  has_many :bookings
end
```

**3. bookings.rb**

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :class_price
end
```

**4. bookings_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
end
```

I'm using the Simple Form gem, and due to the restriction in amount of code I can have, this is the header of my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@classs.class_prices, @class_price.bookings.new] do |f| %>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `to_model' for #<ClassPrice::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fcf01a70ff8>
Did you mean?  to_xml
```

Edit:

**5. class_prices_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @classs = Classs.find(params[:classs_id])
  @class_price = ClassPrice.find(params[:id])
  @booking = Booking.new
  @classs.class_prices.find(params[:id]).bookings.create(booking_params)
end
```

Comment: Btw, you can use `Klass` instead of `Classs`.

Comment: Right, haha. Thank you.

I expect my form to create a new Booking/edit a Booking on the ClassPrice show page (i.e. sitename.com/classs/class_id/class_price/class_price_id)

Comment: If you only want to create a single `Booking` record in your form, and have no fields from other models, then you don't need a nested form. Try with: `simple_form_for(@booking) do |f|`. I am not sure about the URL it will generate for form to submit. But that can be handled.

Comment: Please add your `class_prices_controller` `show` action to the question. This is the relevant controller action for the classprice show page.

Comment: I've edited to include the mentioned controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `to_model' for ClassPrice::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fcf01a70ff8

`@classs.class_prices` returns a collection and the *first argument* in the `simple_form_for`(or any other form helpers) should **never** be a *collection*. I believe it should be

```
<%= simple_form_for [@class_price, @class_price.bookings.new] do |f| %>
```

**Update:**

As per your *routes*, it should be

```
<%= simple_form_for [@classs, @class_price, @booking] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error:

undefined method `class_price_bookings_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fffe48031a8>:0x00007f57f46be1c8>
Did you mean?  classs_class_price_bookings_path

Comment: @CepheausC I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Suggestion: You could also take a look at [shallow nesting](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) which would simplify your routes and allow you to make @Pavan's first answer work.

Comment: You say the following: "the *first argument* ... should **not** be a *collection*" However I can't think of an example where any argument is a collection. The only thing that comes to mind is `[:admin, @post]` where `:admin` is the namespace, but it still isn't a collection. I suggest changing it to "an argument should **never** be a *collection*" or something like that.